# Reusing Eclipse Run menu in Eclipse RCP application

Tags: java, eclipse-rcp

I want to create an eclipse RCP application for a custom language. A programs which is written using the cutom language should be run and show it's output when the user click on the Run button.

Is it possible to integrate eclipse Run menu in eclipse RCP application with it's default features as we create NEW menu item by using ActionFactory? If it is possible how to do that?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Huh? Can you explain or show an example of what you are trying to do?

Answer (score 3):

If you "just" want the Run menu along with the default entries, just include a dependency to `org.eclipse.debug.ui`.

You will then need to add launch configuration types for your specific language using the various extension point from the plugins `org.eclipse.debug.core` and `org.eclipse.debug.ui`.

As always, when it comes to the more advanced functionality of Eclipse, the easiest way to get access to the functionality is via resources and examples. Although it is a bit dated, the article "We Have Lift-off" (http://www.eclipse.org/articles/Article-Launch-Framework/launch.html) is the best starting point for this. Have a look at the various references to `org.eclipse.debug.core.launchConfigurationTypes` to find the best example to use asa starting point - in particular the ANT Build stuff as this is pretty simple...

In general you can find the plug-in that contributes a specific entry using the PDE Menu Spy (`Alt-Shift-F2` on MacOS)...

Comment: Also see http://wiki.eclipse.org/FAQ_How_do_I_support_source-level_debugging_for_my_own_language%3F for suggestion on setting up your launch config type.